# How can I dispatch same method to be called multiple times and give call order number as parameter in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda, dispatcher

I needed to dispatch a method for each view model only once and all worked nice. Now I need to dispatch SelectedObjectsChanged-call for one of the view models (ObjectViewModel below) 2 times so I introduced property NumberOfCalls and parameter for both methods. However SelectedObjectsChanged is called only once and the value for parameter callNumber is wrong (2) while I thought it would be 0 first time and 1 second time. How this should be done correctly?

```
interface ISelectedObjectDependent
{
    void SelectedObjectsChanged(int callNumber);
    int NumberOfCalls { get; }
    int ExecutionOrder { get; }
    bool NeedsRefresh(int callNumber);
}

public class SelectedObjects
{
    private List<ISelectedObjectDependent> _viewModels; 
    public void ObjectSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var vm in _viewModels)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vm.NumberOfCalls; i++)
            {
                if (vm.NeedsRefresh(i))
                {
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
                        (Action)(() => 
                   {
                       vm.SelectedObjectsChanged(i);
                   }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectViewModel : ViewModel, ISelectedObjectDependent
{
    public int NumberOfCalls { get { return 2; } }

    public int ExecutionOrder { get { return 1;} }

    public bool NeedsRefresh(int callNumber)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void SelectedObjectsChanged(int callNumber)
    {
         if (callNumber == 0)
         {
            if (IsObjectInfoVisible && IsObjectInformationExpanded)
                RefreshObjectInfo(false);
         }
         else
         {
             if (IsObjectInfoVisible && IsObjectInformationExpanded)
                 ObjectProperties.Instance.UpdateRemainingAttributes();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The lambda expression does not capture the value of the variable `i`. Rather, it captures the variable itself (so to speak). When the lambda expression is eventually executed through the dispatcher, the for-loop has already been finished, with `i` having the value `2`. That's the value SelectedObjectsChanged is being called with (it actually is being called twice, both with an argument of 2)

Comment: Solution: Create a variable inside the for-loop and assign it the current value of `i`. Then use that variable instead of `i` inside the lambda expression (this works as the lambda is also local to the for-loop body scope; i.e. with each iteration of the for-loop, a new capture will be created)

Comment: thanks @elgonzo! calling once instead of twice problem was kind of unrelated so introducing new variable solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time SelectedObjectsChanged executes the value has changed

```
var index = i;                    
App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)(() => 
               {
                   vm.SelectedObjectsChanged(index);
               }));
```

**Helpful comment by PhillipH**

> All delegate style code blocks in .net have the same scenario. If you
>   are passing an iterated variable, it does not get evaluated until the
>   code block is executed. You think it gets evaluated when you create
>   the code block, but its a misreading of the code

Comment: This is the correct solution but because all delegate style code blocks in .net have the same scenario. If you are passing an iterated variable, it does not get evaluated until the code block is executed. You think it gets evaluated when you create the code block, but its a misreading of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Parameter is correct now and I found out the reason for "calling once instead of twice". +1 for @PhillipH for helpdul comment.